# can't install purrr on R 3.5.1

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Just installed R 3.5.1 and get this error

```
library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
package ‘purrr’ was installed by an R version with different internals; 
it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

OK I'll go ahead and `install.packages("purrr")` and I get this error.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘purr’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

What do I do?

Comment: "package **purr** is not available", I think it's a typo.

Comment: Looks like item #1 at the [accepted answer at the dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721890/903061).